# How to find variance with sum of all $x$ and sum of all $x^2$?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

The Edinburgh Scale is a test that is commonly used in geriatric studies in order to assess the cognitive
performances of elderly people. The score of the scale ranges from $0$ to $500$ point. The normal score
for an elderly person (without specific mental or cognitive disorders) can be modelled by a Normal
distribution with mean $266$ points and standard deviation $16$. In a retirement home of the city of Berlin
to a random sample of $61$ elderly people the Edinburgh Scale was administered, and the score
collected. The relevant statistics were

$$\sum x = 15568,\quad
\sum x^2 = 4054484.$$

At $5\%$ significance, is there statistical evidence that the variance of the sampled population differs from that of the normal score for an elderly person?

Let me show you how I attempted to find the variance for the problem. I have no issue with knowing how to solve the actual problem itself, but I am getting the wrong variance somehow.

$$\sum\frac{x}{n} = \frac{15568}{61} = 255.2131147541 = \text{mean}$$

$$V(x) = \frac{4054484 - 255.2131147541^2}{61} = 65,399.184$$

However, this is wrong as per my professor's notes. The correct value for variance is $1355.4372$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The variance is the mean of the squares minus the square of the mean.

Comment: I think the fraction bar is too wide.

Comment: @Gribouillis and robjohn Thank you very much - that is exactly what my error was